# difference in meaning "sleep for eighteen hours" and "sleep eighteen hours"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

If I want to answer to how many hours the babies sleep,
which of the following sentence is suitable.

> Babies sleep eighteen hours.
>
> Babies sleep for eighteen hours.

What is the difference in meaning between "for eighteen hours" and "eighteen hours"?

I would like to learn about the difference between the two sentences in general, in order to decide when to use
which.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference in meaning.  Both phrases express the same temporal duration, one with the preposition **for**, the other without the preposition.

> I've been waiting two hours.
>
> I've been waiting for two hours.